# find default() value from variable

Tags: c#, generics

Is it possible to get the default value from a variable?

```
public static int CountNonDefault<T>(this T[] v)
{
    int count = 0;

    foreach (var item in v)
    {
        if (item.GetType != default(typeof(item)))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
item.GetType != default(item.GetType().GetProperty("Value").PropertyType)
item.GetType != default(typeof(item));
item.GetType != default(item.GetType());
```

Comment: What does item.GetType return?

Comment: Appears to return the correct type, but when nested as default(item.GetType()) compiler yields the error "'item' is a variable but is used like a type"

Comment: @JamesDudley No need for that, check my answer below. Just use `default(T)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `item` variable is of generic type `T` then how about  `default(T)`:

```
T defaultValue = default(T);
foreach (T item in v)
{
    if (item != defaultValue)
    {

    }
}
```

To use `!=` to compare two objects of type `T` you must change your method like this:

```
 public static int CountNonDefault<T>(this T[] v) : where T : EqualityComparer<T>
```

If that is not an options for you, then you can follow this alternative:

```
T defaultValue = default(T);
foreach (T item in v)
{
    if(item == null && defaultValue == null || (item.Equals(defaultValue)))
    {

    }
}
```

This is to prevent `.Equals()` from throwing a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: It works!  Sticking with your second example for now as I'm not familiar with Constraints on Type Parameters; looks like I have some reading to do!